# How would i turn this into a flat surface?

Tags: modeling

Look at this image and explain how i could smooth this out please.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `relax` command (<kbd>W</kbd> -> `LoopTools` -> `Relax`) from LoopTools add-on:

[image]
[image]

LoopTools included in blender, you can enable  it in user preferenses.

Answer (score 0):

Probably by selecting all verticies and then running the smooth command a number of times. You can access this a number of ways, but the easiest is via the "Specials Menu" (Press W)